# Is it best practice to update one's own question or to ask a new one?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'd like to know more about [unknown old FIDE players](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21711/unknown-old-fide-players). I wanted to update my question by adding few players but the question has been edited for a very reasonable reason:

> Please do not change the question after is has been asked; if you want to know something new, ask a new question.

I fully understand this reason, but is it reasonable to ask a second question that will be very similar to the first? I mean, the big difference will be that I will be asking about new names for which I cannot find information. The alternative would be to update my question by adding some few names. What is best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about different players then please ask a new question, particularly since the previous question is almost 2 years old and it would make existing answers look incomplete.